# dealing with .doc file in python and getting a limited list of character

Tags: python, openoffice.org, doc

I know it .doc files could not be directly read in python. Thus, when I read it in python using `os.open()` and `os.read()` I get the following result no matter how long the actual document is, I want to know what these characters are?

```
b'\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1'
```

Comment: Do you mean which characters they represent? `ÐÏà¡±`

Answer (score 1):

It is the signature of an OLECF file:

[http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/OLE_Compound_File#File_signature](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/OLE%5fCompound%5fFile#File%5fsignature)

The OLECF is used to store:

- Microsoft Office 97-2003 documents:

  - Word Document (DOC)
  - Excel Spreadsheet (XLS)
  - Powerpoint Presentation (PPT)
- MSN (Toolbar) (C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Local Settings\Application  - Data\Microsoft\MSNe\msninfo.dat)
- Jump Lists
- StickyNotes.snt
- Thumbs.db
- Windows Installer (.msi) and patch file (.msp)
- Windows Search (srchadm.msc)

For more information, see [Compound Binary File Specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/E/0BE8BDD7-E5E8-422A-ABFD-4342ED7AD886/WindowsCompoundBinaryFileFormatSpecification.pdf)

That being said, reading .doc files is not an easy way to extract text from MS Word files. You may try [python-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx) library if the files you are dealing with are .docx files.